# SQL: how to get views count from multiple articles sorted by category?

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySQL and I have a code that gets last 6 articles from each category:

```
select a.*
from article a
where a.created >= coalesce((select a2.created
   from article a2
   where a2.category = a.category
   order by a2.created desc
   limit 5, 1
  ), a.created
 );
```

Now I need also get total views for each article from another table. How to do that? This does not work:

```
select a.*, Count(view.*) as CountViews
from article a
where a.created >= coalesce((select a2.created
   from article a2
   where a2.category = a.category
   order by a2.created desc
   limit 5, 1
  ), a.created
 ) left join view on a.id = view.post_id;
```

Example of printing articles by categories: https://nedvigimostmsk.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest using a subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select count(*)
        from views v
        where a.id = v.post_id
       ) as num_views
from article a
where a.created >= coalesce((select a2.created
                             from article a2
                             where a2.category = a.category
                             order by a2.created desc
                             limit 5, 1
                            ), a.created
                           );
```

The problem with your query is that you are using `COUNT()` with no `GROUP BY`.  Either this returns an error (with default setting in the more recent versions of MySQL) or it returns one mysterious row.  You can fix this with a `GROUP BY`, but a correlated subquery often has better performance -- particularly with the right indexes.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also please advise me how to change article `created` sorting? I mean this sql query prints last 6 articles, but they are in `asc` instead if `desc`

Comment: @sirjay . . . You can add an `order by` to the outer query to get the ordering you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since Gordon appears to be offline right now I'll post my edit here as another answer. This should give you the order by that you want.

```
    select a.*,
           (select count(*)
            from views v
            where a.id = v.post_id
           ) as num_views
    from article a
    where a.created >= coalesce((select a2.created
                                 from article a2
                                 where a2.category = a.category
                                 order by a2.created desc
                                 limit 5, 1
                                ), a.created
                               )
ORDER BY a.created DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Gordon, You can also make a join on a nested query that count and group from the `views` table

```
select a.*, v.cnt as total_views
from article a
inner join 
    (
        select post_id, count(*) as cnt from views group by post_id
    ) v on a .id = v.post_id
where a.created >= coalesce((select a2.created
   from article a2
   where a2.category = a.category
   order by a2.created desc
   limit 5, 1
  ), a.created
 );
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you also please advise me how to change article `created` sorting? I mean this sql query prints last 6 articles, but they are in `asc` instead if `desc`

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

```
... )left join view on a.id = view.post_id 
GROUP BY a.*
```

Also, in your SELECT statement, use this instead of COUNT(view.*) AS CountViews

```
COUNT(view.post_id) AS CountViews
```

Generally speaking, it's better to list out the specific columns you want to return rather than just using `SELECT a.*`

Comment: Thank you! Can you also please advise me how to change article `created` sorting? I mean this sql query prints last 6 articles, but they are in `asc` instead if `desc`